# Android: draw circles on canvas with in a time cycle

Tags: android, animation, canvas, draw

I want to draw circles on a canvas with increasing/decreasing diameter every second, in order to create a "blinking" effect. I tried to use a runnable, but probably I'm using it wrong, because nothing happens... Maybe somebody with more experience can help, or give me another idea to create this type of effect...Thanks a lot

```
  public void drawLocation(Canvas c, Float posx, Float posy){  
    paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
    paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    final Canvas canvas =c;
    final float px = posx;
    final float py = posy;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10;i++) {
        Log.i("drawLocation", "i = " + i);
        final int p = i;
        final Runnable r=new Runnable()
            {
            public void run() 
                {
                    canvas.drawCircle(px,py, p*scale, paint);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    Log.i("drawLocation", "Delay 1000 ms ");
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: As far I can see You must force the draw to happen. Issue invalidate to let the ui be drawn again. ( or is this method called on onDraw ??? )

Comment: Right, you should check if you have calld this method in     onDraw() and     invalidate() call is must after each paint llike canvas.drawCircle(px,py, p*scale, paint);invalidate();

Comment: no, it's not called in onDraw() - it can't work without onDraw? invalidate() it's not working either, Eclipse says the method is undefined for my type of Activity...